# How to import in ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

How can I translate `var exec = require('child_process').exec`;
to ES6? I know the following: `import exec from 'child_process';`

What I don't know is how to add the `.exec` at the end to the ES6 syntax.

Comment: Try `import { exec } from 'child_process'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I translate var exec = require('child_process').exec; to ES6?

You do:

```
import { exec } from 'child_process';
```

> I know the following:  import exec from 'child_process';

That's actually wrong, it is as I've done above. More on `import` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import).

Otherwise, is simply:

```
import child_process from 'child_process';
const exec = child_process.exec;
```

You CANNOT do anything like:

```
import exec from 'child_process'.exec;
```

Comment: The curly bracket format in `import` statements is _not_ destructuring, calling it that is misleading. It is its own entirely separate syntax, since you do `{ exec as myExec }`, not `{ exec: myExec }`.

Comment: @loganfsmyth: I've updated my answer with the correction